# Android App Development: Effort Estimation tools

Tags: software-development, estimation

The intention is to determine raw estimates effort in man hours for the development of Android app, based on basic Screen UI/Wireframes.

For example: Design team provided 10-screens. Based on the judgement of development team, and looking at the screen UI, we divided it into **Simple, Medium complex and Complex Screens**

Also, since this is mobile app, which fetch its data using Web Service using JSON we also need to estimate the backend integration effort for the same.

Are there any tools (web-based or any other form) available, using which the effort in man hours can be calculated for Android App development?

Comment: Questions asking for software recommendations are off topic for this site. You could try the Software Recommendations SE site here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions - However also note nvoigt's answer below- You will not find a tool that can do this.

Answer (score 3):

## No

Ask the person that will do the work, how much time s/he will need. If you are not happy with that, ask someone else, until you find what you are looking for. But you won't find a magic wand that you can wave to get a calculated amount of man-hours that an unknown person of unknown skill will need for an unknown amount of work.

That will not work for *any* business and software development is no exception.

Answer (score 1):

The team of developers who actually will be doing the work should estimate on the screens. There is **NO** tool to do this automatically.

Developers will identify the backend/server side code to write for fetching the data,applying the business validation, etc.
To come up the estimates in man hours, the team need to know well the interfaces and services they need to tap into and the screens should be more or less complete in design. 
You will need to add spikes for unknown and they stay as unknown until they are worked on by the team. The outcome of a spike could alter your estimates.

Do the same with QA to get an estimate on testing the application.